# Why kotlin doesn't allow covariant mutablemap to be a delegate?

Tags: delegates, jvm, kotlin, generic-variance

I'm new to Kotlin.
When I learn [Storing Properties in a Map](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#storing-properties-in-a-map). I try following usage.

```
class User(val map: MutableMap<String, String>) {
    val name: String by map
}
```

```
class User(val map: MutableMap<String, in String>) {
    val name: String by map
}
```

```
class User(val map: MutableMap<String, out String>) {
    val name: String by map
}
```

The first two are both work, the last one failed.
With `out` modifier, the bytecode of `getName` like this:

```
  public final java.lang.String getName();
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  getfield kotl.User.name$delegate : java.util.Map [11]
     4  astore_1
     5  aload_0 [this]
     6  astore_2
     7  getstatic kotl.User.$$delegatedProperties : kotlin.reflect.KProperty[] [15]
    10  iconst_0
    11  aaload
    12  astore_3
    13  aload_1
    14  aload_3
    15  invokeinterface kotlin.reflect.KProperty.getName() : java.lang.String [19] [nargs: 1]
    20  invokestatic kotlin.collections.MapsKt.getOrImplicitDefaultNullable(java.util.Map, java.lang.Object) : java.lang.Object [25]
    23  checkcast java.lang.Object [4]
    26  aconst_null
    27  athrow
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 28] local: this index: 0 type: kotl.User
```

As we can see, it will cause a `NullPointerException`.

Why contravariant is not allowed on a map delegate?

And why kotlin doesn't give me a compile error?

Comment: You shouldn't be able to use contravariance there, since the map _produces_ values. The fact that you don't get a compiler warning is likely a bug. Actually `out` makes in covariant, `in` makes it contravariant. For _some_ reason, using `in` produces the code I would expect with `out`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah... the compiler is definitely wrong here. (testing with Kotlin version 1.1.2-5)

First of all, in the case of property delegation to a map, you use the name of the property to look up a value for it in the map.

Using a `MutableMap<String, in String>`, is equivalent to Java's `Map<String, ? super String>` which uses *contravariance*.

Using a `MutableMap<String, out String>`, is equivalent to Java's `Map<String, ? extends String>` which uses *covariance*.

(you mixed the two up)

A covariant type can be used as a producer. A contravariant type can be used as a consumer. (See [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397). sorry, I don't have a Kotlin specific link, but the principle still applies).

Delegation by map uses the second generic type of map as a producer (you get things *out* of the map), so it should not be possible to use a `MutableMap<String, in String>` since it's second parameter is a consumer (to put things into).

For some reason, the compiler generates the code it needs for a `MutableMap<String, out String>` in the case of a `MutableMap<String, in String>` and this is wrong, as you can see in this example:

```
class User(val map: MutableMap<String, in String>) {
    val name: String by map
}

fun main(args:Array<String>){
    val m: MutableMap<String, CharSequence> = mutableMapOf("name" to StringBuilder())
    val a = User(m)

    val s: String = a.name
}
```

You will get a class cast exception, because the VM is trying to treat a `StringBuilder` as a `String`. But you don't use any explicit casts, so it *should* be safe.

Unfortunately, it generates garbage (`throw null`) in the valid use case of `out`.

In the case of `String` it doesn't really make sense to use covariance (`out`), since `String` is final, but in the case of a different type hierarchy, the only work around I can think of is to manually patch the bytecode, which is a nightmare.

I don't know if there is an existing bug report. I guess we'll just have to wait until this gets fixed.

Comment: Thanks. So it just a bug.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: it's not a bug in the compiler, but rather an unfortunate consequence of how the signature of `operator getValue()` is declared for `MutableMap`.

**Long answer**:
[delegating properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html) to maps is possible because of the following three operator functions in the standard library:

```
// for delegating val to read-only map
operator fun <V, V1: V> Map<in String, @Exact V>.getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): V1

// for delegating var to mutable map
operator fun <V> MutableMap<in String, in V>.getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): V

operator fun <V> MutableMap<in String, in V>.setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: V)
```

Here the use-site variance of the `MutableMap` receiver is chosen so that one could delegate a property of some type to a map which can store its supertype:

```
class Sample(val map: MutableMap<String, Any>) {
    var stringValue: String by map
    var intValue: Int by map
}
```

Unfortunately, when you try to use an out-projected `MutableMap<String, out String>` as a delegate for a `val` property and consequently as a receiver of `getValue` operator, here what happens:

- `MutableMap<in String, in V>.getValue` overload is choosen, because it has more specific receiver type.
- Since the receiver map has `out String` type argument projection it's unknown what its actual type argument is (it can be a `MutableMap<..., String>` or a `MutableMap<..., SubTypeOfString>`), so the only safe option is to assume it is `Nothing`, which is a subtype of all possible types.
- The return type of this function is declared as `V` which has been inferred to `Nothing`, and the compiler inserts a check that the actual returned value is of type `Nothing`, which should always fail, as there couldn't be a value of type `Nothing`. This check looks like `throw null` in the bytecode.

I've opened an issue [KT-18789](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18789)  to see what we can be done with the signature of this operator function.

**UPD**: The signature was fixed in Kotlin 1.2.20

Meanwhile as a workaround you can cast the `MutableMap` to `Map`, so that the first overload of `getValue` is chosen:

```
class User(val map: MutableMap<String, out String>) {
    val name: String by map as Map<String, String>
}
```